# jquery click image select next span without class or id

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a text line to an image without an id or a class I have a series of images such as

```
  <img src="../img/star.png"  /><span>no text here until left img is clicked</span>

  <img src="../img/someotherpicture.png"  /><span>no text here until left img is clicked</span>

  <img src="../img/anotherpicture.png"  /><span>no text here until left img is clicked</span>
```

and for jquery i have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img").click(function(){  
$("img").next.$("span").val("info inserted after clicking on the img next to spa");
})
});
```

I'm a little bit confused as to how i should use next here, or maybe i should use find? I always have an img followed by a span.

Comment: Use `$(this).next().text("your text goes here")`

Comment: jQuery's `.next()` is a function, not a property, so you need parentheses. http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: With your current code, it is only possible to put the same text for all of them. There must be some way to distinguish between the `img`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selectors and methods are incorrect.  In order to target the span, use:

```
$(this).next('span')
```

Then, to change the text inside a node, use `.text()` instead of `.val()`:

```
 $(this).next('span').text('info inserted after clicking on the img next to spa');
```

(.val() is used for input fields).

Comment: This won't work because $('img') doesn't refer to the clicked img.

Comment: @Wing Lian - You're correct.  Code edited to reflect correction.

Answer (score 2):

You should also consider using .on() over .click(), but the most important piece is $(this) within the callback which will refer to the clicked object

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("img").on('click', function(e){  
        $(this).next('span').text("info inserted after clicking on the img next to span");
    })
});
```